# NLP: Find the most similar Corpus (not Document)

Tags: nlp, data-science, gensim, topic-modeling

I'm looking for suggestions on how to approach a document classification problem.  I will explain by means of example:

**Problem statement**

I have a collection of papers published by a university.  I have another collection published by another university.  And so on, for many universities.

When a new paper comes in, I'd like to determine which university probably published it.

**My current approach**

1. For each university, build a dictionary of all terms from all papers with frequencies.  Preprocess into terms and build a gensim `Dictionary` per university.
2. Build a "master" dictionary by merging all of the university-specific dictionaries.  Iterate and perform `master_dictionary.merge_with(university_dictionary)`
3. Treat each university dictionary as a document in a new corpus. Turn it into a BoW representation, and build a model from that.  TfIdf/LSI/LDA.
4. Perform a similarity match of the new paper (as BoW) against the model.  Find the university dictionary document that matches closest.

**My question**

How is a problem like this tackled? (And is there a name for this?)

- I'm currently comparing a new document with a summarized document, one per university.
- I could compare a new document with every document across all universities.  Then get the universities for the top matching documents using metadata.
- I've run across the Author-Topic Model but haven't looked into it, but that seems like this may be a good fit.

Any other ideas?